# Finitely generated group (locally cyclic)

Tags: abstract-algebra

A group G is said to be locally cyclic if every finitely-generated subgroup of $G$ is cyclic.

a) prove that $G$ is locally cyclic if and only if every pair of elements in $G$ generates a cyclic subgroup.

b) prove that a locally cyclic group is Abelian.

c) prove that any subgroup of locally cyclic group is locally cyclic .

This is what I have got so far :

a) let every pair of elements in $G$ generates a cyclic subgroup.
$\longrightarrow$ by definition, $G$ is locally cyclic. Conversely, suppose that $G$ is locally cyclic then every finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is cyclic. If $H$ contains $\{e\}$, then $H$ is cyclic. If $H$ does not contain $\{e\}$ then $H=\{a^n,a^m\}$ where $m$ isthe smallest positive integer such that $a^m \in H$. But if we consider q and r such that $n=mq+r$ with $0\leq r<m$ by the division algorithm. $a^n=a^{mq+r}$=$(a^{m})^{q},  a^{r} \in H$ obviously, $a^{n}$ cab be written as some powers of $a^{m}$. Thus, $H$ is a cyclic group. 
A locally cyclic group $H$ has every pairs of elements in $G$ generates a cylic subgroup . This implies, Every element can be written as some power of e such that $b=a^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
$$
bc=a^{n}a^{m}=a^{n+m}=a^{m+n}=a^{m}a^{n}=cb.
$$
Thus, $G$ is Abelian.

would someone please be willing to verify my work and give a hint to finish it out.

Answer (score 0):

Any subgroup $H$ of $G$ contains $e$, so your casework in a) doesn't make sense. It doesn't follow directly from the definition that if every pair of elements generates a cyclic subgroup, then $G$ is locally cyclic. You need to use induction. There is also no need to use the division algorithm for the other direction. Here are some hints:

a) For locally cyclic implies pairs generate cyclic subgroups, note that a subgroup generated by two elements is finitely generated. For the other direction, let $H = \left<x_1,\ldots,x_n\right>$ be a finitely generated subgroup of $G$. You know that if $n = 2$, then $H$ is cyclic. Use induction on $n$.

b) Your idea here is correct, but I am confused by your phrasing "power of $e$". Powers of the identity are just the identity.

c) Let $H$ be a subgroup of a locally cyclic group $G$. Any finitely generated subgroup of $H$ is also a finitely generated subgroup of $G$.

Comment: would you help me out a bit more in order to understand it.

Comment: Suppose $G$ Is locally cyclic. Let $a,b \in G$. Then $\left<a,b\right>$ is finitely generated, and hence cyclic. So pairs of elements generate cyclic subgroups. Now suppose pairs of elements in $G$ generate cyclic subgroups. Let $H = \left<x_1,\ldots,x_n\right>$ be a finitely generated subgroup of $G$. The base case $n = 2$ is given by hypothesis. Now $\left<x_1,x_2\right> = \left<x\right>$ for some $x \in G$, so $H = \left<x,x_3,\ldots,x_n\right>$, hence $H$ is generated by $n - 1$ elements. So by induction, $H$ is cyclic.

Comment: That is been a great help. Any idea about part (b) ?

Comment: You already had the right idea. The point is that for any pair $a,b \in G$, the subgroup $H = \left<a,b\right>$ is cyclic, i.e $H = \left<c\right>$ for some $c \in G$. Therefore $a = c^n$ and $b = c^m$ for some $n,m \geq 1$, so $a$ and $b$ commute.

Comment: Thank you so much. for part (c) can I conclude that  from part(a) we know that every pair of element in G generates a cyclic subgroup. And we already know that a subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Comment: would someone please verify part (c) for me.

Comment: Let $H$ be a subgroup of a locally cyclic group $G$. Every finitely generated subgroup of $H$ is a finitely generated subgroup of $G$, hence...